# Generating combinations of elements in distinct sets using python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Is there a more pythonic way to write this code. I  am trying to find all combinations of 2 elements in different distinct sets  but excluding combinations between members in the same set. So if 0 and 1 are in the same set I dont want the combination 01.

I would prefer a module which does this. I looked at https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
but  this required inputting a single list, and giving the combinations of its elements. I want to input multiple sets.

I suppose I could use itertools.combinations to generate all combinations, then substract those in the same set but that  seems wasteful.  Is there a better way?

### Example 0

#### Input

setA = [0, 1, 4]

setB = [2, 3]

#### Expected output

edge contains (['02', '03', '13', '12', '42', '43'])

### Example 1

#### Input

setC = [0,2]

setD = [1]

setE = [3]

#### Expected output

edges contains set['32', '31', '01', '21', '30']

### Code

```
edge= set()
edges= set()
setA = set([0, 1, 4])
setB = set([2, 3])
setC = set([0,2])
setD = set([1])
setE = set([3])

print "Two set combinations of elements (not between elements in same set)"

for i in setA:
    for j in setB:
        if str(i)+str(j) in edge:
            pass
        edge.add( str(i)+str(j) )

print edge


print "Three set combinations of elements (not between elements in same set)"


for i in setC:
    for j in setD:
        if str(i)+str(j) in edges:
            pass
        edges.add( str(i)+str(j) )
        for k in setE:
            if str(k)+str(i) in edges:
                pass
            edges.add( str(k)+str(i) )
            if str(k)+str(j) in edges:
                pass
            edges.add( str(k)+str(j) )


print edges
```

Comment: can you please post and example input - output pair? The indentation is also a bit off.

Comment: You want to add combinations of **every two elements**?

Comment: Every time i read the question it makes less and less sense. ☺

Comment: You also check whether the `str(i)+str(j)` is in the set, but regardless whether it is, you do the same thing.

Comment: OP, what would happen if `setA = [0, 1, 4]` and `setB = [2, 4]`? Would `"04", "14"` be allowed? How about `"44"`?

Comment: It's not clear why some combinations are not included in your example outputs, and others are. Could you clarify your intent?

Comment: Furthermore in the second example the order of the elements seems to be reversed...

Comment: 44 is not allowed
04 is not allowed
14 is allowed

Comment: @Dave and `"14"` is??

Comment: sets are distinct so if 1 and 4 are in elements in different sets then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this itertools one-liner?

```
C = [0,2]
D = [1]
E = [3]

import itertools as it

print [list(it.product(x, y)) for x, y in it.combinations([C, D, E], 2)]
```